# Pandas dataframe pivot or stack and sort

Tags: pandas, dataframe, stack, pivot

I'm trying to get summary data out of a dataframe.

I have summary data for ~500 stocks' performance derived from code like this:

`close_prices_normalized = close_prices / close_prices.iloc[0]`

The head() looks like this:

```
                 AAL      AAPL       AAP  ...       ZBH      ZION       ZTS
2018-01-10  3.646102  2.568596  1.401648  ...  1.615425  2.168600  2.236309
2018-01-11  3.825085  2.583186  1.431559  ...  1.612261  2.200083  2.256884
2018-01-12  3.964068  2.609861  1.469455  ...  1.609756  2.207125  2.281089
```

The last row contains the information I want, but I don't want to scroll sideways for 500+ columns looking for the highest number - and I want to use the information programmatically.

So, I've gotten the last row like this:

`pt = close_prices_normalized.tail(1)`

Now, I need to rotate the information so the symbols are in a column next to the information, and I need to sort by the values.

I know this *should be* simple, but I'm just unable to figure it out.

I can't make any version of pivot work because I don't have a column name it will accept for the values.

I've tried

```
perf_list = pt.stack()
perf_list.head()


2018-02-07  AAL     3.484746
            AAPL    2.351218
            AAP     1.393283
            ABBV    3.134345
            ABC     2.009384
dtype: float64
```

I don't understand why the date is still there or how to get rid of it.

This is apparently not a dataframe?

So, if I want column names to try to refer to, I have to do this:

```
stupid = pd.DataFrame(perf_list)
stupid.head()
```

But, the output looks identical?

And, if I try to assign column names, it will allow me to assign to the numerical column:

```
stupid.columns=['perf']
```

However, it doesn't think the other column is a column. If I try to assign column names to both:

```
stupid.columns=['symbol','perf']

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

I've tried all sorts of .reindex and .reset_index with various options, but I'm just shooting in the dark and can't find any sort of reference for how to do this seemingly-simple thing.

Sorry if this is just "too-noob"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC try [`reset_index(level=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html#pandas-series-reset-index) after [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas-dataframe-stack) then rename the columns:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'AAL': {'2018-01-10': 3.646102, '2018-01-11': 3.825085,
            '2018-01-12': 3.964068},
    'AAPL': {'2018-01-10': 2.568596, '2018-01-11': 2.583186,
             '2018-01-12': 2.609861},
    'AAP': {'2018-01-10': 1.401648, '2018-01-11': 1.431559,
            '2018-01-12': 1.469455}
})

perf = df.stack().reset_index(level=1)
perf.columns = ['symbol', 'perf']

print(perf)
```

`perf`:

```
           symbol      perf
2018-01-10    AAL  3.646102
2018-01-10   AAPL  2.568596
2018-01-10    AAP  1.401648
2018-01-11    AAL  3.825085
2018-01-11   AAPL  2.583186
2018-01-11    AAP  1.431559
2018-01-12    AAL  3.964068
2018-01-12   AAPL  2.609861
2018-01-12    AAP  1.469455
```

Comment: Thank you guys so much for helping the frustrated noob. So grateful.